# Generic recognition command for bison

Tags: bison

I am developing a bison program and need to have a last option that allow it to recognize anything. Much like a else if...

Thanks

```
commands: F{
            t[top++] = 'F';
            }
      |PLUS{
            t[top++] = '+';
            }
      |MINUS{
            t[topo++] = '-';
            }
      |ACOL { 
            t[top++] = '[';
            }
      |FCOL{
            t[top++] = ']';
            }
      |POINT{
             t[top++] = '.';
            }
      |EQUAL {
            t[top++] = '=';
            }
      | {  
           /* generic command should be here
           if any of the commands above were found it should run whatever is here*/
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the logic that you want to run after any command token has been recognized in a marker non-terminal, like the following.  Notice that the right side of `marker`'s production doesn't match any tokens.

```
command_and_marker: command marker;

command:  F
            {
            t[top++] = 'F';
            }
        | PLUS
            {
            t[top++] = '+';
            }
        | MINUS
            {
            t[topo++] = '-';
            }
        | ACOL
            { 
            t[top++] = '[';
            }
        | FCOL
            {
            t[top++] = ']';
            }
        | POINT
            {
            t[top++] = '.';
            }
        | EQUAL
            {
            t[top++] = '=';
            } 
marker:     {  
            /* generic command should be here
            if any of the commands above were found it should run whatever is here*/
            }
```

I have formulated my answer to match the comments in the code, which are somewhat at odds with the text of your question.  If you want `command` to match anything, not just `F`, `PLUS`, etc., then you will have to spell out all of the tokens that your lexer can generate in productions for `command`.  This is not necessarily a good idea, for several reasons.